# Model binding using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am using **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** for model binding and validate my ASP.NET MVC application.

I have a C# model class like this

```
public class Employee
{
    public Int64 EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit the form via AJAX to insert a record, the values are set to `Employee` object correctly.

But `ModelState.IsValid` statement is false always and it says **The EmployeeId field is required**.

Since `EmployeeId` is an identity column in the database, I do not set it in controller.

How can I fix this issue?

When I update a record, I need to make `EmployeeId` as required. How can I handle this also?

Comment: actually if you can't solve that error and want to get rid of that then just clear that error from Modelstate.....ModelState.Remove("{key}"); to remove error

Comment: You can add the attribute `[Bind(Exclude = "EmployeeId ")] ` in your method where you are posting your form to. It would look something like: `public ActionResult InsertRecord([Bind(Exclude = "EmployeeId")] Employee employee)`

Comment: Since insert and update happens in the same function, `[Bind(Exclude = "EmployeeId")]` attribute cannot be added I think. `ModelState.Remove("{key}");` will help.

Comment: @AutumnValentine Ahh I see. I was not aware of that fact. Well then `Remove` should work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think simplest/cleanest is to make `EmployeeId` nullable:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public Int64? EmployeeId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```